# .innerHTML <br> breaking

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

Why is this breaking? I've not used .innerHTML correctly before and don't know why this would be wrong.

```
function asdf() {
    document.getElementById("qwerty").innerHTML="A<br>
      B<br>
      C<br>
      D<br>";
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "breaking"?

Comment: Hope the problem is not because of \ !!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to escape new-lines in JavaScript string-literals:

```
function asdf() {
    document.getElementById("qwerty").innerHTML="A<br>\
      B<br>\
      C<br>\
      D<br>";
}
```

Though you could, potentially more-easily, simply insert newlines in the string itself:

```
function asdf() {
    document.getElementById("qwerty").innerHTML = "A<br>\nB<br>\nC<br>\nD<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Javascript string literals cannot contain newlines.

You can escape the newlines with backslashes:

```
var myString = "a\
b";
```