# .innerhtml converts <br/> tag to <br>

Tags: javascript, xhtml, innerhtml, internet-explorer-10

I am trying to get the innerhtml of an html element which contains self closing br tags`<br/>` but using .innerhtml converts the `<br/>` to `<br>` tag. I am working with IE10 And it has no XHTML parser to get innerhtml. This is the html:

```
<div>
<span>line 1<br/>line 2<br/>line 3</span>
</div>
```

I want to retain the self closing tag as it is but want to avoid using regEx. Can anyone help me with some other approach to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990441/innerhtml-br-breaking  Please see if this helps

Comment: is <br> not working for IE10 ????

Comment: i need to store it in xhtml format later.

Comment: It works as desired when you serve up the HTML file as XHTML to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

`innerHTML` converts it to `<br>` because it should be [`<br>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) in html. If you want to use it as `<br />` in XHTML, you could replace `<br>` with `<br />` after getting the inner html. You could refer to the sample below:

```js
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
var b = a.innerHTML.split("<br>").join("<br />");
console.log(b);
```

```html
<div>
  <span>line 1<br />line 2<br />line 3</span>
</div>
```